# Link field is removing query parameters

Tags: 8, hooks, configuration

We have an `Article` that a link field, `field_link`. When we create a new page of type `Article`, we set the link field to have a `URL` of `www.example.com/somepath?someid=123345` and label of `View`. When the page is rendered, we are seeing the query parameter is being removed (i.e. `?someid=123345`). We are not doing any `hooks` or extra logic in `twig` templates to remove the query parameters.

How can we prevent the query parameters from being removed when rendering the `field_link` field?

Current behavior when link is rendered:

```
<a href="www.example.com/somepath">View</a>
```

Expected behavior

```
<a href="www.example.com/somepath?someid=123345">View</a>
```

Comment: which config you set to your link field, `Both internal and external links` ? i tested it it works.

Comment: I feel like the link fields want a scheme for external urls, e.g. https://

Comment: @berramou that setting is what was missing.

Comment: Great, so it working now ?

Comment: @berramou yes, i also had to add `https://`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In review, we had the wrong setting for the link. By setting `Both internal and external links`, the link was displaying properly with the `query` parameters.

In Summary

1. `Both internal and external links` should be set on the `field setting`
2. Ensure to use `https://` in the beginning of the `url`